# How to Increase the Patch Search Range for Turtles

Tags: netlogo

I'm new in netlogo, and i want to know is it a right way to set turtles vision by using this code?

```
set leader patches in-radius vision
```

the vision is set as slider and can change from 0-10. The problem is, when i vary the vision from 0-10, seems nothing is change in turtles behavior. Really need some advice on this. thanks for help.

```
to setup
setup-leader
end

to setup-leader
ask max-n-of 10 turtles [count turtles in-radius 3] 
[
set leader? true
set color black
set size 1.5
set leader self
set leader patches in-radius vision
]
end
```

Comment: thanks @Seth Tisue for the feedback, what i'm trying to do is to set leader has ability to see entire environment. what the full coding to do are;there are 4 rules agents must obey when alarm is triggered, follow leader, flocking behavior, obstacle avoidance and evacuate. for flocking rule, i understated the vision is nearest leader, however for leader I still do not quite understand how to make sure the leader has the advantage of looking at the whole environment. so that when emergency happen leader has advantage to help agents move to nearest doors(set as red patches)  asap. tq

Answer (score 0):

This part of your code doesn't make sense:

```
set leader self
set leader patches in-radius vision
```

If you set `leader` twice in a row, the second `set` overwrites the first, so you might as well just omit the first.

In itself, this line:

```
set leader patches in-radius vision
```

could be correct, depending on what you're trying to do, although calling a variable containing a patch set `leader` is strange.

re: "when i vary the vision from 0-10, seems nothing is change in turtles behavior", impossible to comment without seeing the code for the turtles behavior. (If you were expecting `set leader ...` to have some effect on the turtles behavior all by itself, that won't happen. That one line just sets a variable. If nothing is looking at the value of that variable, then nothing further will happen as a result.)

I'd suggest looking at some of the many models in Code Examples and Sample Models that give turtles some kind of "vision", so for example Flocking, Fireflies, and so forth.